# Why do my sql statements fail to accept the posted html form data and insert it into my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I've been working on a sales associate portal for a while. I've done a number of things so far, but have been constantly plagued by ajax or sessions not transferring data when they ought to. Regardless I decided to try and simplify everything, and so my recent problem is that upon entering information into the form (the table certainly isn't the prettiest for now), it appears to submit but makes no change upon my database.

edit_quotes.php

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive fixed-table-body">
        <div id="customer_table">
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >Quote Number</th>
                    <th >Line Description (1)</th>
                    <th >Line Price (1)</th>
                    <th >Line Description (2)</th>
                    <th >Line Price (2)</th>
                    <th >Line Description (3)</th>
                    <th >Line Price (3)</th>
                    <th >Comment</th>
                    <th >Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        ?>   
        <tr>
            <td ><?php echo $row["qid"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l1desc"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l1price"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l2desc"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l2price"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l3desc"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["l3price"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["comment"]; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <form action="submit_edit_quote.php" method="post">

             <td ><input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-warning" /></td>
            <td ><input type="text" id="l1d" name="l1d" ></td>
            <td ><input type="text"  id="l1p" name="l1p" ></td> 
            <td ><input type="text"  id="l2d" name="l2d" ></td>
            <td ><input type="text" id="l2p" name="l2p" ></td>
            <td ><input type="text"  id="l3d" name="l3d" ></td>
            <td ><input type="text"  id="l3p" name="l3p" ></td>
            <td ><input type="text"  id="comment" name="comment"></td>
            <td ><input type="text"  id="email" name="email"></td>
            <td><input type=hidden name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>" id="<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>"></td>
            </form>   
        </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

submit_edit_quote.php

---

```
<?php 

//inserts the updated customer data in the db
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
 $quote = $_POST["hidden"];
    if(!empty($_POST)){
      $output = '';  
      $message = '';
      mysqli_select_db($connect, 'sales_associates_db');
      $l1d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l1d"]);
      $l1p = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l1p"]);
      $l2d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l2d"]);
      $l2p = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l2p"]);
      $l3d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l3d"]);
      $l3p = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["l3p"]);
      $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["comment"]);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["email"]);
      if($quote != '')  
      {  
          $query = "INSERT INTO customer_quotes_db
          SET l1desc = $l1d,
          l1price = $l1p,
          l2desc = $l2d,
          l2price = $l2p,
          l3desc = $l3d,
          l3price = $l3p,
          comment = $comment,
          email = $email
          WHERE qid= $quote";
          $message = 'Data Updated';  
      }

      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
        {  
            $output .= '<label class="text-success">' . $message . '</label>';    
        }  
        echo $output; 
        header('Location: edit_quotes.php'); 
        exit();
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: `insert`s can't have `where` clauses because the data shouldn't exist. You also should use prepared statements with parameters, not escaping. It is unclear how you submit this data because the form has no `submit` button. Are you using JS/ajax, if so you should add that to the question. Your `id`s also are not unique which could cause issues if that is how you are addressing these elements.

Comment: Did you try with quotation? like  this l1desc = '".$l1d."' if still not work the use var_dump($_POST) to check values received or not.

Comment: Actually, upon rereading since you say `Data Updated` you should change `INSERT INTO` to `update`. Additional, you have the quoting issue @Navbro has noted. Use prepared statements though and that would resolve that issue.

Comment: Forget all this hideous (and useless) escaping stuff. See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries. Your problems will magically disappear